# Composition of limits given two separate limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Just wanted to check whether my limit manipulation is correct.
Assume we know that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 2} f(x) = 3$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 3} g(x) = 4$. Then is it always the case that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 2} g(f(x)) = 4$? The way I went about doing this is that $$g(\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 2} f(x)) = g(3) = 4$$

Comment: For this to work $g$ should be continuous at $3$.

Comment: do we really need continuity? since we know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} g(x) = 4$

Comment: The problem is that $f(x)$ can equal $3$ even if $x \neq 2$. So the value of $g(3)$ matters.

Comment: You are passing the limit inside to $f$, i.e. you are trying to do the following: $\lim_{x \to 2}g(f(x))=g\left(\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)\right)$

Comment: So since we dont know the continuity of $g$, we cannot conclude my result right? Since it could be the case that $g(3) \neq 4$?

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ See my example below. Things could be even worse.

Comment: The result holds with the additional hypothesis that $f(x) \neq 3$ as $x\to 2$. Without this restriction there is no guarantee.

Comment: This is based on the law of limit of composite functions. _If $f(x) \to b$ and $f(x) \neq b$ as $x\to a$ and $g(x) \to L$ as $x\to b$ then $g(f(x)) \to L$ as $x\to a$_.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=\frac{4x-12}{x-3}$. So $g$ is defined for $x \neq 3$ and is equal to $4$, so  $\lim_{x\to 3}g(x)=4$.

Let $f(x)=\frac{3x-6}{x-2}$. So $f$ is defined for $x \neq 2$ and is equal to 3, so $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=3$.

But $g(f(x))$ is only defined for $x$....??? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take this example

$$f(x)=3 \; if\; x\ne 2 \; and \; f(2)=0 $$

$$g(x)=4\; if \; x\ne 3\; and \; g(3)=5$$

we have
$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=3$$
$$\lim_{x\to 3}g(x)=4$$
But
$$g(f(x))=5\; if \; x\ne 2\; and \;g(f(2))=4$$

and
$$\lim_{x\to 2}g(f(x))=5$$